# Persist certain elements on screen without refreshing when navigating

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using stacknavigator, whenever user navigates to a new screen everything on the screen flashes out, then back in even if the elements are the same on both starting and ending screen. For example, I have a searchbar at the top of every page and sticky footer at the bottom. Is there any way to keep those elements on the screen during the navigation?

Ideal result is like with Tabnavigator, the tabs stay on screen during navigation.

Comment: just put ur search bar and footer at root component

Comment: That does work but I didn't see a way to place the searchbar below the stacknavigator header, only above. Any ideas?